# Program randomly adds to variable

Tags: c++

my program seems to be running fine but at certain points the variable healthone seems to be added on too instead of being subtracted from like its supposed to be although there isnt a line in this code to adding to healtone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float healthone, healthtwo, ending;
    int attack, move, random, chance, comprandom, attackp, attackcp, rando;
    char c;
    string comattackname;

    cout << "Do you want to be Naruto or Goku? [n or g]: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << " n";

    cout << "Naruto and Goku enter the ring!" << endl;
    cout << " n";

    healthone = 23;
    healthtwo = 23;
    ending = 10;

    while (ending >= 0) {
    if (c == 'n') {
        cout << "What move do you want to use?" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Tail Beast Bomb" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Rasengan Shurikan Barrage" << endl;
        cout << "3 - Giant Rassengan Barrage" << endl;
        cout << "4 - Rassengan Barrage" << endl;
        cout << "5 - Rassengan Shuriken" << endl;
        cout << "6 - Rasengan" << endl;
        cout << "7 - Direct Punch" << endl;
        cout << "8 - Shuriken" << endl;
        cout << "9 - Enter Sage Mode" << endl;
        cout << "10 - Enter Limited Tail Beast Mode" << endl;
        cout << "11 - Enter 9 Tails Mode" << endl;
        cout << "-";
        cin >> move;
    }

    if (c == 'g') {
        cout << "What move do you want to use?" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Universal Spirit Bomb" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Super Spirit Bomb" << endl;
        cout << "3 - Continuos Kamehameha" << endl;
        cout << "4 - Super Kamehameha" << endl;
        cout << "5 - Kamehameha" << endl;
        cout << "6 - Destructo Disk" << endl;
        cout << "7 - Direct Punch" << endl;
        cout << "8 - Ki Blast" << endl;
        cout << "9 - Enter Sage Mode" << endl;
        cout << "10 - Enter Limited Tail Beast Mode" << endl;
        cout << "11 - Enter 9 Tails Mode" << endl;
        cout << "-";
        cin >> move;
    }

    if (move == 8) {
        attackp = 1;
        rando = 23;
    }

    if (move == 7) {
        attackp = 2;
        rando = 17;
    }

    if (move == 6) {
        attackp = 3;
        rando = 12;
    }

    if (move == 5) {
        attackp = 5;
        rando = 8;
    }

    if (move == 4) {
        attackp = 8;
        rando = 5;
    }

    if (move == 3) {
        attackp = 12;
        rando = 3;
    }

    if (move == 2) {
        attackp = 17;
        rando = 2;
    }

    if (move == 1) {
        attackp = 23;
        rando = 1;
    }


    chance = 1 + rand() % 23;
    if (chance <= rando) {
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Hit! Dealing " << attackp << " Damage!" << endl;
        healthtwo = healthtwo - attackp;
    } else {
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Miss!" << endl;
    }


    comprandom = 1 + rand() % 8;

    if (comprandom == 8) {
        attackcp = 1;
        rando = 23;
    }

    if (comprandom == 7) {
        attackcp = 2;
        rando = 17;
    }

    if (comprandom == 6) {
        attackcp = 3;
        rando = 12;
    }

    if (comprandom == 5) {
        attackcp = 5;
        rando = 8;
    }

    if (comprandom == 4) {
        attackcp = 8;
        rando = 5;
    }

    if (comprandom == 3) {
        attackcp = 12;
        rando = 3;
    }

    if (comprandom == 2) {
        attackcp = 17;
        rando = 2;
    }

    if (comprandom == 1) {
        attackcp = 23;
        rando = 1;
    }


    if (c = 'n') {
        if (comprandom == 1) {
        comattackname = "Tail Beast Bomb";
        }
        if (comprandom == 2) {
        comattackname = "Rasengan Shurikan Barrage";
        }
        if (comprandom == 3) {
        comattackname = "Giant Rassengan Barrage";
        }
        if (comprandom == 4) {
        comattackname = "Rassengan Barrage";
        }
        if (comprandom == 5) {
        comattackname = "Rassengan Shuriken";
        }
        if (comprandom == 6) {
        comattackname = "Rasengan";
        }
        if (comprandom == 7) {
        comattackname = "Direct Punch";
        }
        if (comprandom == 8) {
        comattackname = "Shuriken";
        }
    } else if (comprandom == 1) {
        comattackname = "Universal Spirit Bomb";
    }
    if (comprandom == 2) {
        comattackname = "Super Spirit Bomb";
    }
    if (comprandom == 3) {
        comattackname = "Continuos Kamehameha";
    }
    if (comprandom == 4) {
        comattackname = "Super Kamehameha";
    }
    if (comprandom == 5) {
        comattackname = "Kamehameha";
    }
    if (comprandom == 6) {
        comattackname = "Destructo Disk";
    }
    if (comprandom == 7) {
        comattackname = "Direct Punch";
    }
    if (comprandom == 8) {
        comattackname = "Ki Blast";
    }

    chance = 1 + rand() % 23;
    if (chance <= rando) {
        cout << "Comp Used " << comattackname << "!" << " Hit!" << " Dealing " << attackcp << " Damage" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        healthone = healthone - attackcp;
    } else {
        cout << "Comp Used " << comattackname << "!" << " Miss!" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    cout << "Your health: " << healthone << endl;
    cout << "Comp health: " << healthtwo << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;


    if (healthone > healthtwo) {
        ending = healthone;
    }

    if (healthone < healthtwo) {
        ending = healthtwo;
    }

    if (healthone = healthtwo) {
        ending = healthone;
    }


    if (healthone <= 0) {
        cout << "You loose." << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    if (healthtwo <= 0) {
        cout << "You win." << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger? Also, don't link to code, put it in your question.

Comment: You can find the answer in my text editor. Take special note of the very elegant construction used in the `Gizmo` wrapper.

Comment: My format gets messed up though. And whats debugger? Sorry im new :P

Comment: Did you initialize the value for attackcp at the start of your code?  Do you have an initial value for all your variables?

Comment: I initialized but im still having the same problem

Comment: Also Kerrek SB where do I find your "text editor"

Comment: @user3144703: That was some heavy sarcasm, since you didn't put your code into your question.

Comment: Im sorry i didnt mean to be sarcastic

Comment: Please post your code.  Also, please post a run of the output showing why you think healthone is being added to.  What sequence leads to it...you got to give to get...

Comment: @user3144703: The other way round. Kerrek was sarcastic. By the way, you have so much duplicate code, you should group your data correctly. Also, if you search for "debugger" in your favorite search engine, you will find some information how to use one, which will help tremendously in finding the routes of such errors.

Comment: I am **never** sarcastic.

Comment: Well posting your code is a good idea - but narrow it down a little. 200+ lines of code is excessive

Comment: If you want to use text pasting services to post your code, you should try www.pastebin.com. It allows for proper indentations, syntax coloring, and displays code in constant width fonts

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas: You commented ___three times___ that he should add the code, instead of suggesting an edit yourself?

Comment: I looked at the code and saw it.  Others have posted code via pastebin , etc., and gotten their stuff answered.  I figured withholding the answer once I saw it, especially since I had to go roast marshmallows with the kids, was a lose-lose.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/

Answer (score 3):

This line is your problem:

```
if (healthone=healthtwo)
{
     ending=healthone;
}
```

Change it to:

```
if (healthone==healthtwo)
{
    ending=healthone;
}
```

I don't know about your IDE, but many of them will flag something like this as a warning.  Check your warnings...

Comment: Wow man thank you so much! That worked amazingly! I cant thank you enough!